# Join a table using a wildcard / default value

Tags: sql, join, sql-server-2008-r2, wildcard

I am trying to join two tables and use a `*` to join on any rows that have an empty string...

For example

**Table A:**

```
Fund Name, Fund Code
Fund A, 12345
Fund B, 34567
Fund C, 99999
Fund D, 44444
```

**Table B:**

```
Fund Name, FundMail
Fund A, johndoe@gmail.com
Fund B, janedoe@gmail.com
*, default@gmail.com
```

**Desired Result:**

```
Fund A, 12345, johndoe@gmail.com
Fund B, 34567, janedoe@gmail.com
Fund C, 99999, default@gmail.com
Fund D, 44444, default@gmail.com
```

I have googled this quite a bit but can't seem to wrap my head around it...

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
select a.FundName, a.FundCode, b.FundMail
from tableA a join
     tableB b
     on a.FundName = b.FundName or b.FundName = '*';
```

That isn't quite right, because everything will match the `*`, so the above will return duplicate rows.

It think you want it phrased like this:

```
select a.FundName, a.FundCode, coalesce(b.FundMail, bd.FundMail) as FundMail
from tableA a left join
     tableB b
     on a.FundName = b.FundName left join
     tableB bd
     on b.FundName = '*';
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it in 2 steps:

```
declare @defaultEmail varchar(50)

select @defaultEmail = fundMail
from tableB
where FundName = '*'

select a.FundName, 
a.FundCode, 
isnull(b.fundMail, @defaultEmail) as EMail
from tableA as a
left join tableB as b
on a.FundName = b.FundName
order by 1, 2
```

Comment: I can't hardcode in the email as it is actually coming from a table.

Comment: Ok, I changed my answer to pull it from a table.